# Cocos2dx launcher - how do I set a newer engine version?

Tags: cocos2d, cocos2d-x

Why doesn't Cocos(V3.10) detect my newer engine version (3.14) which I downloaded and placed into the engine folder? ( I mean the launcher, the all-in-one version where you can create your project much easier)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are talking about the cocos studio launcher. It is a cancelled project, they dont give more support to it. 
However, you can still using cocos studio for GUI/level designing and then importing it to your 3.x newer version.